# Why does useState react hook cause Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following script:

```
const [customers, setCustomer] = useState([]);

  if(users.results){
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if(role.role.name === 'ADMIN'){
          admins.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    let x = []
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if (role.role.name === 'CUSTOMER') {
          x.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    setCustomer(x);
  }
```

Trying to call `setCustomer` causes the **Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.** error. I can't seem to find the reason why.
How do I set the customers to the value of `x` without causing the above error?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
const Administration = props =>{
  const { fetchUsers, users, loading_users } = props;
  const usersPerPage = 9

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
    
  let admins = [];
  const [customers, setCustomer] = useState([]);

  if(users.results){
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if(role.role.name === 'ADMIN'){
          admins.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    let x = []
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if (role.role.name === 'CUSTOMER') {
          x.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    setCustomer(x);
  }
```

Comment: The `useState` hook isn't doing that, it's because you're calling `setCustomer` each time you render; what's your expected behavior? I think we're missing some key information here, like what is `users` and when are you expecting _that_ to change?

Comment: @Jacob I have updated the code. `users` is a prop that is updated when the `fetchUsers` call is successful. I want some bits of the `users` which am calling `customers` and `admins` and I want to manage their state inside the `Administration` component...

Comment: @EsirKings can you provide definition for your fetchUsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to update customer with `setCustomer` when `users` updates. Placing this in a `useEffect` with `users` as a "only call this when this changes" option can do that for you. It also looks like `admins` is supposed to be state:

```
const [admins, setAdmins] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(users.results){
    let admins = [];
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if(role.role.name === 'ADMIN'){
          admins.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    setAdmins(admins);

    let x = []
    users.results.filter(user => {
      user.roles.filter(role => {
        if (role.role.name === 'CUSTOMER') {
          x.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    setCustomer(x);
  }
}, [users]);
```

Now this will only run on mount and when the `users` state changes.